# Unpaired t-test with only summary means

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, mean, descriptive-statistics

Is it appropriate to conduct an unpaired t-test with only summary means from both groups?

For example, let's say you want to compare:

a. Professor A's scores received on a evaluation by **his** students from one semester; with
b. The average evaluation scores among all professors in the university completed by **all** students from the same semester.

The teacher evaluation has 15 Likert questions (6-point scale). Constraints:

1. You don't know how many students completed the evaluations in either group.
2. All you have is 15 mean scores for Professor A, and 15 mean scores for the overall university sample.

It's safe to assume the evaluation is psychometrically sound.

An unpaired t-test is conducted to compare means from group 1 (15 means from Professor A's students) and group 2 (15 means for all professors in the University). So $N = 30$.

Is this appropriate?

Comment: Welcome to the site. If this is a homework question, please add the "self-study" tag. See [homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812)

Comment: Just wanted to add - my main question is the appropriateness of using N = 15 for each group. I'm aware you can conduct a t-test with only summary statistics from each group (e.g., mean, SD, and sample size), but the sample size is usually the number of *individuals* contributing to the data - not the number of *questions*

Comment: Hint: think about t-test's assumpion of independent observations.